# MySQL consolidate duplicate data records via UPDATE / DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, union

I have a table which looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Colors;
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ USERNAME ║  RED   ║ GREEN  ║ YELLOW ║  BLUE  ║ ORANGE ║ PURPLE ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ joe      ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
║  2 ║ joe      ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║
║  3 ║ bill     ║ 1      ║ 1      ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 1      ║
║  4 ║ bill     ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
║  5 ║ bill     ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
║  6 ║ bob      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
║  7 ║ bob      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 1      ║
║  8 ║ bob      ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ (null) ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I would like to run an `UPDATE` and `DELETE` which would find and remove duplicates and consolidate the records such that we would end with this as the result.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Colors;
╔════╦══════════╦═════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ USERNAME ║ RED ║ GREEN  ║ YELLOW ║  BLUE  ║ ORANGE ║ PURPLE ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ joe      ║   1 ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║
║  3 ║ bill     ║   1 ║ 1      ║ 1      ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ 1      ║
║  6 ║ bob      ║   1 ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 1      ║ (null) ║ 1      ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I know I could easily do this with a script, but in the interest of learning and understanding MySQL better I would like to learn how to do this using pure `SQL`.

Comment: I suppose you meant to say `DELETE`, not `UPDATE` if you want to remove records.

Comment: FrankPI, you are correct. I have updated the question to include `DELETE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a projection. It doesn't update the table nor delete some data.

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID,
        Username,
        MAX(Red) max_Red,
        MAX(Green) max_Green,
        MAX(Yellow) max_Yellow,
        MAX(Blue) max_Blue,
        MAX(Orange) max_Orange,
        MAX(Purple) max_Purple
FROM    Colors
GROUP   BY Username
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdb3b/1)

**UPDATE**

if you really want to delete those records, you need to run UPDATE statement first before you can delete the records

```
UPDATE  Colors a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  MIN(ID) min_ID,
                    Username,
                    MAX(Red) max_Red,
                    MAX(Green) max_Green ,
                    MAX(Yellow) max_Yellow,
                    MAX(Blue) max_Blue,
                    MAX(Orange) max_Orange,
                    MAX(Purple) max_Purple
            FROM    Colors
            GROUP   BY Username
        ) b ON a.ID = b.Min_ID 
SET     a.Red = b.max_Red,
        a.Green = b.max_Green,
        a.Yellow = b.max_Yellow,
        a.Blue = b.max_Blue,
        a.Orange = b.max_Orange,
        a.Purple = b.max_Purple
```

Then you can now delete the records,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    Colors a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  MIN(ID) min_ID,
                    Username
            FROM    Colors
            GROUP   BY Username
        ) b ON a.ID = b.Min_ID 
WHERE   b.Min_ID  IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8635/1)

Comment: Using my proposal below, you do not need an intermediate UPDATE, but just one DELETE

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to update the underlying table?  If not (and you simply want the resultset as shown in your example), you could simply group the table:

```
SELECT   MIN(ID)     AS ID,
         Username    AS Username,
         MAX(Red)    AS Red,
         MAX(Green)  AS Green,
         MAX(Yellow) AS Yellow,
         MAX(Blue)   AS Blue,
         MAX(Orange) AS Orange,
         MAX(Purple) AS Purple
FROM     Colors
GROUP BY Username
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4160f/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Colors c1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Colors c2
               WHERE c1.Username = c2.Username
                 AND ((c1.Red    IS NULL AND c2.Red    IS NULL) OR c1.Red    = c2.Red   )
                 AND ((c1.Green  IS NULL AND c2.Green  IS NULL) OR c1.Green  = c2.Green )
                 AND ((c1.Yellow IS NULL AND c2.Yellow IS NULL) OR c1.Yellow = c2.Yellow)
                 AND ((c1.Blue   IS NULL AND c2.Blue   IS NULL) OR c1.Blue   = c2.Blue  )
                 AND ((c1.Orange IS NULL AND c2.Orange IS NULL) OR c1.Orange = c2.Orange)
                 AND ((c1.Purple IS NULL AND c2.Purple IS NULL) OR c1.Purple = c2.Purple)
                 AND c2.ID < c1.ID
             )
```

The nulls make this a bit more complex, as NULL = NULL is not true but unknown in SQL. If you had 0 and 1, the part before the OR in the color conditions could be omitted.